# Angular Service Not Being Shared in Module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm working on an Angular project in which I'm lazy loading feature modules, and I've encountered a strange error in one of my modules.

I'm providing a service at the module level using the "providers" property of NgModule. I would expect (and have been able to use services this way before) that the service would be shared across all components in the module. However, when I inject the service into components in my module, they are injected as separate instances.

In my project, I have two components which I've observed this in, a list component and an edit component. I set a value in my service while I'm in the list component which I'm trying to share with the edit component, but when I route from the List Component to the Edit Component, the service is re-instantiated, and the same for when I go from Edit Component to List Component.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I've been able to use shared services in modules before, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code for the Components, Module, and Service:

List Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Project } from '../../../shared/models/project';
import { ProjectService } from '../../project.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-list-main',
  templateUrl: './project-list-main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-list-main.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectListMainComponent implements OnInit {
  private projects$: Observable<Project[]>;
  private selectedItem: Project;

  onSelectedItem(event){
    this.selectedItem = event;
  }

  editProject(){
    this.projectService.setEditProject(this.selectedItem);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/projects/edit');
  }

  deleteProject(){
    this.projectService.delete(this.selectedItem.id);
  }

  constructor(private router: Router, private projectService: ProjectService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projects$ = this.projectService.projects;
  }
}
```

Edit Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProjectService } from '../../project.service';
import { Project } from '../../../shared/models/project';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-edit-main',
  templateUrl: './project-edit-main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-edit-main.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectEditMainComponent implements OnInit {
  public projectForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() editProject: Project;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private projectService: ProjectService) { }

  saveProject(event){
    this.projectService.add(event);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/projects');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['',Validators.required],
      description: [''],
      type: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.projectService.editProject.subscribe(editProject => {
      if(editProject)
        this.projectForm.patchValue(editProject);
    });
  }
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Project } from "../shared/models/project";
import { DataService } from "../shared/services/data.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AlertService } from "../shared/alert/alert.service";

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
    private _projects: BehaviorSubject<Project[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    projects: Observable<Project[]> = this._projects.asObservable();
    private _editProject: BehaviorSubject<Project> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    editProject: Observable<Project> = this._editProject.asObservable();

    editing: boolean = false;

    private dataStore: {
        projects: Project[]
    };

    loadall() {
        this.dataService.GetAll("projects")
            .subscribe(projects => {
                this.dataStore.projects = projects;
                this._projects.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).projects);
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.alertService.error('Error', 'Encountered error while loading Projects');
            });
    }

    setEditProject(editProject: Project){ 
        this._editProject.next(editProject);
        this.editing = true;
    }

    add(project: Project) {
        this.dataService.Add('projects', project).subscribe(project => {
            this.dataStore.projects.push(project);
            this._projects.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).projects);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.alertService.error('Error', 'Encountered error while adding Project');
        });
    }

    update(project: Project) {
        let editId = this._editProject.getValue().id;
        project.id = editId;
        this.dataService.Update('projects', editId, project).subscribe(() => {
            this.dataStore.projects.forEach((p, i) => {
                if (p.id === project.id) { this.dataStore.projects[i] = project; }
            });
            this._projects.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).projects);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.alertService.error('Error', 'Encountered error while updating Project');
        });
        this.editing = false;
        this._editProject.next(null);
    }

    delete(id: number) {
        this.dataService.Delete('projects', id).subscribe(response => {
            this.dataStore.projects.forEach((p, i) => {
                if (p.id === id) { this.dataStore.projects.splice(i, 1); }
            });
            this._projects.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).projects);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.alertService.error('Error', 'Encountered error while deleting Project');
        });
    }



    constructor(private router: Router, private dataService: DataService, private alertService: AlertService) {
        this.dataStore = { projects: [] };
        this.loadall();
    }
}
```

Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProjectRoutingModule } from './project-routing.module';

// Primeng module imports 
import { CalendarModule, DataTableModule, DialogModule, ConfirmDialogModule, ConfirmationService, PanelModule, DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

// Dumb components
import { ProjectEditComponent } from './edit/project-edit.component';
import { ProjectListComponent } from './list/project-list.component';
import { ProjectCardComponent } from './card/project-card.component';
import { ProjectDetailComponent } from './detail/project-detail.component';
import { ProjectDeleteOptionsComponent } from './delete/project-delete-options.component';

// Containers
import { ProjectEditMainComponent } from './containers/project-edit-main/project-edit-main.component';
import { ProjectListMainComponent } from './containers/project-list-main/project-list-main.component';
import { ProjectComponent } from './project.component';

// Services
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProjectRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DataTableModule,
    DropdownModule,
    PanelModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProjectCardComponent,
    ProjectDetailComponent,
    ProjectEditComponent,
    ProjectListComponent,
    ProjectDeleteOptionsComponent,
    ProjectComponent,
    ProjectEditMainComponent,
    ProjectListMainComponent
  ],
  providers: [ProjectService]
})
export class ProjectModule { }
```

Comment: A piece of code would be useful :)

Comment: Updated with some code

Comment: This might help you: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-di-tree.html

Comment: I found that website as well but I wasn't sure about whether or not that's a recommended approach? If I understand it correctly, by providing the services for the root, wouldn't that be loading the services eagerly in the root DI tree? If I have to resort to this, it seems as though it would massively increase the initial load time.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to import another module (A) if you need the following:

- A directive, component or pipe from the imported module (A)

Knowing this, if you import a module (A), that also provides a service, and you end up with a new instance of that service, then that module (A) could have been wrongly set up since you expected that service to be an application-wide singleton.

A standard module registers services that are available for the underlying components. A shared module, if it also wants the service to be shared, registers services on the root of the application, this can be done with the **.forRoot() method**.

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { authObjService } from './service/authObj';
import { loginGuard } from './service/loginGuard';
import {loginButton} from './directive/login-button/login-button'
import {logoutButton} from './directive/logout-button/logout-button'


@NgModule({
    declarations: [loginButton, logoutButton],
    imports: [CommonModule],
    exports: [loginButton, logoutButton],
})

export class authenticationModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: authenticationModule,
            providers: [authObjService, loginGuard]
        }
    }
}
```